# Testing R package on Travis fails because of TeXLive incompatible versions

Tags: travis-ci, macos

I am writing [an R package](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap) and using Travis for Continuous Integration. The tests on macOS fail because the system has a newer version of TeXLive and is unable to install the `inconsolata` font to build vignettes.

The Travis logs show:

```
sudo tlmgr install inconsolata upquote courier courier-scaled helvetic
tlmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository
http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
  (2016--2018)
do not include the version of the local installation
  (2019).
```

and further on, R is unable to build the vignettes:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
! LaTeX Error: File `inconsolata.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.276 ^^M

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR, 1 WARNING
```

This failure throws a warning for R, which is upgraded to an error because I have `warnings_are_errors: true` in `.travis.yml`.

I tried [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524357/inconsolata-missing-to-build-r-vignette/50243939#50243939) of reinstalling `inconsolata` in `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then
      brew cask install basictex;
      sudo tlmgr update --self;
      sudo tlmgr update --all;
      sudo tlmgr install titling framed inconsolata;
      sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended;
    fi
```

and [this TexStackExchange thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253599/repository-and-local-installation) of changing the TeX repository and running the same commands as Travis does when installing the system:

```
before_install:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then
      sudo tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet;
      sudo tlmgr update --self
      sudo tlmgr install inconsolata upquote courier courier-scaled helvetic;
    fi
```

and neither worked.

How can I install the `inconsolata` font?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to the CTAN mirrors having yet to update. The issue appears in the [Travis R community forum](https://travis-ci.community/t/latex-error-file-inconsolata-sty-not-found-only-on-osx-when-building-r-package/3261):

> might be related to the recent switch to TexLive-2019 as the LaTeX package manager seems to fail finding inconsolata in the repository.
>
> ...
>
> It looks to me like the mirror chosen was has not updated to 2019, so I think this will resolve itself naturally when the mirrors catch up. If not I can look into it.

In the meantime, I solved it by forcing a previous version of TeXLive with a downgrade to OSX 10.12 in `.travis.yml`:

```
# macOS 10.12 version
osx_image: xcode9.2
```

See [this Travis page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx#macos-version) for the correspondence between XCode and OSX versions.