# Travis tests for R package fail with little explanation

Tags: travis-ci

I am writing [an R
package](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap) and using
Travis for Continuous Integration. Tests and `R CMD CHECK` pass locally and for
3 versions of R under Linux (oldrel, release, and devel). All three versions
fail under macOS with no information in the Travis logs:

```
...
R CMD check fail logs
0.01s$ for name in $(find "${RCHECK_DIR}" -type f -name "*fail");do echo ">>> Filename: ${name} <<<";cat ${name};done
log
R CMD check log logs
...
```

I checked in the Travis logs that all the tests I wrote in `testthat` fail. The Travis tests once passed for both Linux and macOS, so I could dissect the code changes to detect the issue, but ideally I could use something more direct and faster than groping in the dark waiting for an answer from Travis.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the recommended setting for R packages of upgrading warnings to errors, i.e. with this line in `.travis.yml`:

```
warnings_are_errors: true
```

then the place to look is the previous heading in the Travis log, called `Checking package`.

#### Example of problem with missing font

In my case, the Travis log under the heading `Checking package` showed that the
`inconsolata` font was missing, so the vignettes failed to build:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
! LaTeX Error: File `inconsolata.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.276 ^^M

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR, 1 WARNING
```

This caused an error for LaTeX, a warning for R, and an error for Travis.

#### Solution to problem

In my case, the problem was due to Travis using TeXLive 2019 and the CTAN
mirrors having yet to update to 2019.

The issue appears in the [Travis R community forum](https://travis-ci.community/t/latex-error-file-inconsolata-sty-not-found-only-on-osx-when-building-r-package/3261):

> might be related to the recent switch to TexLive-2019 as the LaTeX package manager seems to fail finding inconsolata in the repository.
>
> ...
>
> It looks to me like the mirror chosen was has not updated to 2019, so I think this will resolve itself naturally when the mirrors catch up. If not I can look into it.

In the meantime, I solved it by forcing a previous version of TeXLive with a downgrade to OSX 10.12 in `.travis.yml`:

```
# macOS 10.12 version
osx_image: xcode9.2
```

See [this Travis
page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx#macos-version) for the
correspondence between XCode and OSX versions and [the original thread in DevOps
StackExchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8012/testing-r-package-on-travis-fails-because-of-texlive-incompatible-versions/8013#8013).